# Magento 2.1: Errors during compilation - Incorrect dependency in class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, dependency-injection

On Magento 2.1 when installing an extension, the error occurs when compilation:

```
Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
    Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare
        Incorrect dependency in class Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare in /home/webadmin/public_html/app/code/Magebuzz/Socialshare/Block/Socialshare.php
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface already exists in context object
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is self-explained.

`Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare` block class re-injected the dependency `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` in its constructor. 
We can find the original injection from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`.

So to solve it, remove the `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` from the **constructor** in your custom block class `Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare`

Comment: Yes, but what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Remove `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` from the constructor in your custom block class - `Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare`.

Comment: @DevAnd Is it okay? The compilation error is gone?

Comment: this is a good answer. Read the post from maghamed  in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6114. It just mean that this is already injected and ready to use. No need to reinject it and maybe cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

there is a discussion about context on github you can review it on: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6114

for latest version 2.2-develop this validation was removed, there is a pull request that is already merged: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8955

so any future execution of: bin/magento setup:di:compile won't throw errors like:

```
Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
    Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare
        Incorrect dependency in class Magebuzz\Socialshare\Block\Socialshare in /home/webadmin/public_html/app/code/Magebuzz/Socialshare/Block/Socialshare.php
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface already exists in context object
```